# Why I cannot create and open an ofstream in the same code line?

Tags: c++, file, oop, fstream, ofstream

I can do:

```
std::ofstream outfile; outfile.open("foo");
```

but not:

```
std::ofstream outfile.open("foo");
```

since it gives this error:

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    std::ofstream outfile.open("foo");
                         ^
```

as you can also see in the <kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pxc1iiRXzt6mHhKo)</kbd>.

Why?

PS: I know I can just `std::ofstream outfile("foo");`, but I suspect that I am missing a mechanism of C++, that's why I am asking.

Comment: If you want to know why member call is not allowed in object construction you've chosen really bad example. Because 90% of answers would be - you can pass name to ctor.

Comment: The example chose me @Slava. ...and you are right, as the answers section proves.

Comment: @Slava _"you can pass name to ctor"_ Well, no, not really... you cannot name the constructor and you do not directly "call" it in a declaration or initialiser.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am pretty sure Slava means to use the constructor to open the file, by passing the file name as the constructor's first parameter.

Comment: @gsamaras you are right I meant file name indeed.

Comment: @gsamaras Then you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is similar as when you have a function that returns an object and you want to call a method on it in the same line:

```
struct foo { void bar(){} };
foo create_foo() { return foo(); }
```

You can either store the result of `create_foo` or use its return value to call a method, but not both:

```
create_foo().bar();          // OK
auto f = create_foo();       // OK
auto f = create_foo().bar(); // NOPE
```

Back to `ofstream`: You could write

```
std::ofstream().open("foo");
```

but you'd have no chance to get a reference to the `ofstream`.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I'm guessing that if `bar()` returned something (not `void`) that the 3rd case would actually do something.  Maybe not what's expected, but it'd work.

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes. If `bar` would return a reference to `*this`, it would even be possible to get the reference and call the method in the same line, but thats not the case for `std::ofstream::open()`

Answer (score 8):

> Why?

Because the language doesn't permit to combine a declaration with a member function call. The variable `outfile` doesn't even exist until after the declaration.

Use the constructor to open the file:

```
std::ofstream outfile("foo");
```

Comment: I know about the constructor. The answer is this: "Because the language doesn't permit to combine a declaration with a member function call.", which would be nice to have a reference to, or something. Oh well, your edit helps!

Comment: @gsamaras If you already know about constructors, and we all know that you do, I can't see why you asked this question.

Comment: @gsamaras You won't find an explicit reference for this. The language was designed in a particular way, if there had been motivation to allow the code in question then maybe there would have been a way to do it, but I don't see why you'd need it. It's basically asking "why doesn't my car have a jet engine, the manual doesn't say that it has to be missing". Same reasoning - it's not generally needed and would make things more complicated than they have to be. You _could_ create a car that has it (it's not impossible) but it would be a very different car for a very different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't.

Seriously.

C++ has syntax that is permitted, and you shall not write code that does not adhere to it.

There is zero use case for a declaration/expression hybrid using a `void`-returning member function on an object that doesn't exist yet, and without the `=` of an initialiser.

But you knew this already.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're used to something like Java or C# where this type of thing is possible:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
```

Or even Python:

```
lines = open("filename").readlines();
```

The trick here is that with the right "factory functions" you could do this in C++ as well, but that's not how this particular class is made.  The other examples above, with either of these:

```
std::ofstream outfile{"foo"};
auto outfile = std::ofstream("foo");
```

is the "normal" way of doing it in C++.  Part of your disconnect is that the `open()` method returns void:  [std::basic_ofstream::open() doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open).  So when you have this code:

```
std::ofstream outfile.open("foo");
```

It doesn't compile because `open()` is a member function (not static) AND it returns `void` not `std::ofstream`, which is what you declared you're making.

I hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: That guess couldn't be further from wrong Kevin. :/ Yes, indeed it was helpful.

Comment: Well, you win some, you lose some.  But hopefully it was helpful anyways.

Comment: Even if `open()` returned `std::ofstream`, it still wouldn't be valid, because the line is a weird hybrid of declaration and expression, with no initialiser introduced. I don't really understand what gsamaras, who knows C++, is trying to get at with this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to get a better grasp and understanding of the language, sorry if this questions sounds dumb..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know it wouldn't work even with `open()` returning differently, they'd need `auto outfile = std::ofstream::open("foo.txt");` which *does not exist*.  But if such a factory did, they'd be OK.

Comment: Right but aren't all such ruminations totally pointless? We could talk about hypothetical things that don't exist all day; there are infinite of them. I know we're supposed to assume good faith but given OP's background and history and skill this question honestly just seems like trolling to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am sorry for causing you a struggle. thank you though for your answer. Kevin thanks for the insight!

Comment: @gsamaras "to get a better grasp and understanding of the language" Then please go and read http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#nt:init-declarator-list. You just won't find any place in the syntax of a declaration where accessing a member of the declarator would be permitted.

Answer (score 0):

> but not:
>
> `std::ofstream outfile.open("foo");`

This is a plain and simple syntax error. At this point, `outfile` is interpreted as the name of some undefined object. The compiler simply does not understand that you want to create an object of type `ofstream`.

We might naiively hope that we could simply fix it like this:

```
auto outfile = std::ofstream().open("foo"); // call open on a constructed object.
```

The problem is that the method `open` does not return a copy of the `ofstream` so this won't work. (it actually returns void).

Things that will work:

```
// unexciting, but simple - uses a different constructor
std::ofstream outfile{"foo"};
```

This is (IMHO) more readable and also legal:

```
auto outfile = std::ofstream("foo");
```

Comment: Rich, I know! I was wondering why what I tried didn't work, if you could edit your answer into that direction, that would be great!

Comment: @gsamaras yes I see. I'll think about whether there is more insight I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
std::ofstream outfile { "foo" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the language. C++ does not allow such instructions.

Use constructor

`std::ofstream outfile("foo");`

or initialization

`std::ofstream outfile { "foo" };`

Comment: FYI those are _both_ initialization using the constructor